# Copy range using array, insert in new sheet into specific columns

Tags: arrays, vba

I have this code which works, but I need to copy the data into specific column.

How do assign "to" columns from the array? Like value from Sheets("Dataset") column D ends up in Sheets("Forside") column B.

Help is much appreciated

```
Sub filtercopyrange()

Dim x As Long, cls
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim valuee1 As Integer
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ct As Variant

Set sh1 = Sheets("Dataset")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Forside")

Sheets("Forside").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A7:Y5000").Clear

valuee1 = Sheets("Forside").Range("E2").Value

If IsNumeric(valuee1) = False Then
    Exit Sub
Else

    lRow2 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
    Sheets("Dataset").Activate

    valuee1 = Sheets("Forside").Range("E2").Value
    
    iCount = 6
    For i = 2 To lRow2
    
            ct = Range("L" & i).Value
            
            If ct = valuee1 Then
                iCount = iCount + 1
                cls = Array("A" & i, "D" & i, "E" & i, "F" & i, "G" & i, "H" & i, "I" & i, "J" & i, "R" & i, "S" & i)
                With Sheets("Forside")
                    For x = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
                        .Cells(iCount, x + 1).Value = Sheets("Dataset").Range(cls(x)).Value
                    Next x
                End With
            Else
            End If
    
            Next
    
    Sheets("Forside").Activate
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot understand what you want. You posted only **a piece** of code where the variables are not declared and almost all of them are unknown (`ct`, `valuee1` etc.). We can only see that in some circumstances the array is copied **in the sixth row**, starting from its first column. What else do you like doing? Do you want copying it **on a column**, not on a row?

Comment: Added the rest of the code, I basicly wan't to copy certain cells from rows that fits a criteria (valuee1)

Comment: It looked clear enough what you want copying and not so clear **where do you want pasting**... Then, you say "I basically want to copy certain cells from rows that fits a criteria (valuee1)", but at the beginning you say: "Like value from Sheets("Dataset") column D ends up in Sheets("Forside") column B.". What do you want, in fact? In order to copy "cells from rows that fits a criteria" in the column C:C of "Forside" sheet, I tried showing you how to be done in my answer. To copy in B:B it is easy to adapt the code. I commented that part. If you need help you should better explain this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want copying the array content in a column, instead of a row, please try the next approach:

```
Dim strCol as string,iRow as Long, i as Long, lRow2 as Long, ct as string, valuee1 as string
'use the same variable values as in your (not completely seen) code...
strCol = "C" 'column "C:C"
iRow = 2 'the column row, where from the array elements will be copied down
For i = 2 To lRow2
        ct = Range("L" & i).Value
        
        If ct = valuee1 Then
            iCount = iCount + 1
            cls = Array("A" & i, "D" & i, "E" & i, "F" & i, "G" & i, "H" & i, "I" & i, "J" & i, "R" & i, "S" & i)
            With Sheets("Forside")
                For x = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
                    .Cells(x + iRow + 1, strCol).Value = Sheets("Dataset").Range(cls(x)).Value
                Next x
            End With
        End If
Next
```

The above code will copy each array element in column C:C, starting from `iRow` (2, now).